# Android - AlertDialog with RadioButtons, getting AndroidRuntimeException

Tags: android, exception, radio-button, android-alertdialog

I'm developing an Android App which use a SQLite database to store informations. I'm trying to get some of these informations and add them into an AlertDialog with radiobuttons, but when I debug I get this RuntimeException: **requestFeature() must be called before adding content**
I think the error is in:

> shop_type.setContentView(R.layout.shop_list_selection);

but I don't know how to fix it.

Here the code when I click on a ImageButton:

> ```
>     ImageButton shopping = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.gotoshop);
>     shopping.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 
>
>       @Override
>       public void onClick(View v) { 
>
>           // Get infos from DB
>           Cursor lists = dbAdapter.select("ls_tipo_lista", new String[] {"id", "nome"}, null, null, null, null, null);
>
>           // Fetch data if exists
>           if(lists.getCount() > 0)
>           {
>               // Create AlertDialog
>               AlertDialog shop_type = new AlertDialog.Builder(MenuActivity.this).create();
>
>               // Set title and layout
>               shop_type.setTitle("Tipo di spesa");
>               shop_type.setContentView(R.layout.shop_list_selection);
>
>               // Get RadioGroup from shop_list_selection.xml
>               RadioGroup opts = (RadioGroup)shop_type.findViewById(R.id.rbshop);
>
>               // Fetch data
>               while(lists.moveToNext())
>               {
>                   // Create radio button instance
>                   RadioButton rdbtn = new RadioButton(MenuActivity.this);
>
>                   // Add data
>                   rdbtn.setId(lists.getInt(0));
>                   rdbtn.setText(lists.getString(1));
>
>                   // Add to radiogroup
>                   opts.addView(rdbtn);
>               }
>
>                       // Show dialog
>               shop_type.show();
>           }
>       }
>     });
> ```

Here the XML layout:

> ```
> <RadioGroup xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     android:id="@+id/rbshop"      android:layout_width="wrap_content"         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>   android:orientation="vertical" >    </RadioGroup>
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get the error `requestFeature() must be called before adding content` it means you are trying to build your window in the wrong order.
To avoid this error, I suggest taking advantage of the AlertDialog.Builder class:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MenuActivity.this);

// Create the View to populate the RadioButtons
View view = LayoutInflater.from(MenuActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.shop_list_selection, null, false);

// Get RadioGroup from shop_list_selection.xml
RadioGroup opts = (RadioGroup)view.findViewById(R.id.rbshop);

// Fetch data
while(lists.moveToNext())
{
    // Create radio button instance
    RadioButton rdbtn = new RadioButton(MenuActivity.this);

    // Add data
    rdbtn.setId(lists.getInt(0));
    rdbtn.setText(lists.getString(1));

    // Add to radiogroup
    opts.addView(rdbtn);
}

// Set title and layout
builder.setTitle("Tipo di spesa");
builder.setView(view);

// Show dialog
AlertDialog shop_type = builder.create();
shop_type.show();
// This works too for a one-off dialog: builder.show();
```

Comment: Oh, that's great. It works perfectly. Thanks! :) A clarification: setView() is not a method for simple AlertDialog, only for AlertDialog.Builder :)

Comment: I'm glad I could help. To be technical `setView(int)` is not a method in AlertDialog, but `setView(View)` is... Sorry about the confusion I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Call setContentView() after requestFeature().

call  shop_type.show(); just after AlertDialog shop_type = new AlertDialog.Builder(MenuActivity.this).create();